# Netbeans fails FTP upload when encryption is enabled

Tags: encryption, ftp, netbeans, ftps

I recently switched to a new web host, and they offer FTP instead of SFTP. No problem, my regular client (WinSCP) handles this flawlessly, including with (explicit) encryption. However, when I configure NetBeans to automatically upload files to there on save with encryption, I get a strange error when enabling inc.

```
220 ProFTPD Server ready.
AUTH TLS
234 AUTH TLS successful
USER my_username
331 Password required for my_username
PASS ******
230 User my_username logged in
PBSZ 0
200 PBSZ 0 successful
PROT P
200 Protection set to Private
TYPE I
200 Type set to I
CWD /domains/mydomain.org/public_html/dev2
250 CWD command successful
PWD
257 "/domains/mydomain.org/public_html/dev2" is the current directory
CWD /domains/mydomain.org/public_html/dev2/js
250 CWD command successful
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (185,182,56,157,137,191).
STOR examplefile.js.new
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for examplefile.js.new
425 Unable to build data connection: Operation not permitted
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (185,182,56,157,138,255).
STOR examplefile.js.new
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for examplefile.js.new
425 Unable to build data connection: Operation not permitted
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (185,182,56,157,139,229).
STOR examplefile.js.new
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for examplefile.js.new
425 Unable to build data connection: Operation not permitted
DELE examplefile.js.new
250 DELE command successful
QUIT
221 Goodbye.
```

I'm confused. I can login perfectly and even CWD/DELE, but I can't upload files? Some googling pointed me to switching to active mode, but that just results in an eternal synchronizing message followed by a timeout. And it works flawlessly when turning encryption off, or even checking the "only encrypt authentication process". But that's not what I want, since I need to transfer passwords in plaintext in my PHP config file sometimes.

How can I make Netbeans upload files correctly to my host, similar to what other programs (e.g. WinSCP) do? I checked WinSCP's logs and they do encrypt data transfer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FTP is a protocol which uses separate connections to transfer the data and exchanges inside the control connection the ports used for these connections. This makes it very problematic for firewalls because they either need to allow a broad range of possible ports (which weakens the protection by the firewall) or they most detect which ports will be used and dynamically create firewall rules to allow the specific data transfer. The latter is done by analyzing the data stream and extracting and analyzing PORT commandos (active mode) or the response to PASV (passive mode).

This kind of analysis works well if the control connection is not encrypted. But it fails for encrypted control connections since the firewall can no longer see the PORT commands and responses to PASV in clear and thus dynamically create the appropriate firewall rules for the data connections. And this results in the problems you see.

To work around this FTPS (i.e. FTP over SSL, different from SFTP which is file transfer over SSH) provides the CCC command which can be used to switch the control channel back to clear after the authentication is done and thus makes dynamic rule creation work again. But it looks like that Netbeans is not using this. I'm not familiar with the configuration possibilities in Netbeans but look for options on how to enable encryption only for authentication or similar. If there are no such options you are probably out of luck and either need to disable encryption or need to weaken any firewalls which might impact the traffic. Note that in some cases there is no real firewall responsible for the problems but the NAT translation done by routers or ISP, typically also in the context of mobile or DS-Lite connections.

Comment: "look for options on how to enable encryption only for authentication or similar" --> that option is there, as I also wrote in my post, and it works with that enabled, but now it will not encrypt the files that I upload, correct? It cannot be the intention that everyone can read along when I upload or download stuff...

Comment: @user1111929: in theory the control connection can be switched back to plain by using `CCC` but the file transfer still gets encrypted. I don't know if Netbeans supports this but if you find `PROT P` in the debug output with a successful response from the server then you know that the data transfer will be encrypted.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that that's not the case: when activating the "only encrypt authentication process", the output is this: https://pastebin.com/DnmXwEJ2 and it does no longer contain the PROT P (while it did with this option disabled). So... am I understanding correctly that this is a Netbeans issue (and not an issue with my host)? Should I file a bug report with them or is there anything I can do myself?

Comment: @user1111929:  If you consider this a Netbeans issue or if you consider this the inability if your host to support SFTP instead of only FTP(S) or if you consider this a problem with your internet connection in that there is a firewall and/or NAT fiddling with the connection is up to you - a fix of any of these would probably solve your problem.